# Why won't my PXSmartPanel display the correct data after the first execution?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am using a PXSmartPanel to display data from the current row and allow the user to make a choice before manipulating that data.

The first execution works flawlessly.  However, subsequent executions display the first execution's data.  I don't think it's code related, but here's the dialog call:

```
    public PXAction<MXBatch> moveToQueue;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "MoveToQueue")]
    protected virtual void MoveToQueue()
    {
        MXBatch selectedBatch = Batches.Current;
        if (selectedBatch == null) return;

        // Select batch and check for existing mixes
        var batchGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<MXBatchEntry>();
        batchGraph.Document.Current = batchGraph.Document.Search<MXBatch.batchID>(selectedBatch.BatchID);

        if (batchGraph.Transactions.Select().Count > 0)
        {
            Batches.Ask("Already Converted", "This batch already has at least one mix associated with it. This action will be cancelled.", MessageButtons.OK, MessageIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

        var soGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
        soGraph.Document.Search<SOOrder.orderType, SOOrder.orderNbr>(selectedBatch.SOOrderType, selectedBatch.SOOrderNbr);
        SOLine soLine = soGraph.Transactions.Search<SOLine.lineNbr>(selectedBatch.SOLineNbr);

        // Check if Sales Order line exists
        if (soLine == null) Batches.Ask("Missing Sales Order", "The Sales Order item associated with this mix cannot be found. This action will be cancelled.", MessageButtons.OK, MessageIcon.Error);

        // Calculate the current batch weight in CWT
        decimal batchWt = 0m;
        batchWt = INUnitAttribute.ConvertFromTo<SOLine.inventoryID>(soGraph.Transactions.Cache, soLine, soLine.UOM, setup.Current.CwtUOM, soLine.Qty ?? 0, INPrecision.QUANTITY);

        // Calculate the number of mixes
        int maxMixWt = 60; // in CWT
        int mixNbr = (int)Math.Ceiling(batchWt / maxMixWt);
        decimal rcmdMixWt = batchWt / (mixNbr < 1 ? 1 : mixNbr);

        
        // Popup displaying recommended action and allow for change
        if (MixSizeDialog.AskExt((graph, view) =>
        {
            MixSizeDialog.Cache.ClearQueryCache();
            MixSizeDialog.View.Clear();
            MixSizeDialog.ClearDialog();
            MixSizeDialog.Current = new MXMixSize() { BatchSize = batchWt * 100, MixSize = rcmdMixWt * 100, MixNbr = mixNbr };
        }, true) != WebDialogResult.OK) return;
        
        mixNbr = (MixSizeDialog.Current.MixNbr ?? 0);
        mixNbr = mixNbr < 1 ? 1 : mixNbr;

        // Calculate the size of each mix
        decimal mixWt = soLine.Qty.Value / mixNbr;
        
        // Create mixes
        for (int i = 0; i < mixNbr; i++)
        {
            MXMix mix = Mixes.Insert(new MXMix());
            Mixes.SetValueExt<MXMix.qty>(mix, mixWt);
            Mixes.SetValueExt<MXMix.uom>(mix, soLine.UOM);
            Mixes.SetValueExt<MXMix.status>(mix, "QUD");
            Mixes.Update(mix);
        }

        Batches.SetValueExt<MXBatch.status>(selectedBatch, 1);
        Batches.Update(selectedBatch);
        Actions.PressSave();
    }
```

As you can see, my variables are initialized in the block which means they cannot preserve the previous rows values. I added the three lines in the dialog call to clear the data based upon another SO post, but it does not seem to make any difference.

Here's my ASPX:

[image]

What am I missing?

#### Update:

The code that works correctly for me is this:

```
        MixSizeDialog.View.Clear();
        if (MixSizeDialog.AskExt((graph, view) =>
        {
            MixSizeDialog.Cache.Clear();
            MixSizeDialog.Current = new MXMixSize() { BatchSize = batchWt * 100, MixSize = rcmdMixWt * 100, MixNbr = mixNbr };
        }, true) != WebDialogResult.OK) return;
```

Additionally, `AutoRepaint` and `AutoReload` (and possibly `LoadOnDemand`) must be true in ASPX.

Comment: Have you tried adding or verify that your PXSmartPanel has LoadOnDemand="True"  specified?  I have seen that used in other examples, such as, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822530/update-custom-field-on-popup/49862154?r=SearchResults&s=1|41.9898#49862154

Comment: @FarmerJohn, Yes, this is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do/check in order to resolve this:

1. When calling the smart panel view with AskExt ensure that you specify the reload to true. Ex: SmartPanelView.AskExt(true).
2. Ensure that the AutoReload, LoadonDemand and AutoRepaint properties on the smart panel definition are set to true.

You can also try and clear the cache from the smart panel view before calling the AskExt method, but if you specify true for the reload there shouldn't be any need for this.

Comment: Actually, I didn't.  I was trying to clear the view in the smart panel call, but I added ``MixSizeDialog.View.Clear()`` just before the ``AskExt()`` and now it works!  Thank you.  You earned these.