# Acumatica: View not updating UI

Tags: acumatica

When I select InventoryId and click on the button, all requests for this ID are displayed

[inventory id first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1l3H.png)

When I choose another Id, requests for a different Id should appear, but again requests for the first one appear.

[inventory id second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGKuK.png)
[inventory id query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i68Wp.png)

If I delete the first request, the second one is displayed fine, but if I add another InventoryId again, it doesn't work, it always works only with the first one.

[aspx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GECMu.png)

SincPosition = True

What else can you do?

Comment: Check out the update to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64787680/why-wont-my-pxsmartpanel-display-the-correct-data-after-the-first-execution

Comment: I checked all the solutions that were there, everything is as it should be and as it was done in these posts, but it does not work

Comment: ``AutoRepaint`` and ``AutoReload`` are not set in the ASPX you have posted. Did you try it with those settings? As I recall, those were necessary.

Comment: yes, after you wrote, I did everything that was in these posts, but it did not help.
In the debugger, I see how my ID changes and how the necessary elements get into the view, but only the first one is always displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
The problem ended up in aspx.

In 
<px:PXTabItem Text = "Document Details"></px:PXTabItem>

all <px: PXGrid> had "SyncPosition = "True""

As soon as I changed it to SyncPosition = "false" everything worked successfully
```