# Why does my PXSelector ignore what I have selected

Tags: acumatica

I have created a PXGraphExtension on POLandedCostDocEntry.  I have added a PXAction button.  When the button is pressed I show a popup panel to ask the user for a landed cost code.

[image: Popup panel asking for Landed Cost Code]

The problem is that the PXSelector ignores whatever I enter into the field and resets to APPLE (or whatever Landed Cost Code is alphabetically first). If I use the Selector to choose a different code, the code I select is visible for a moment and then immediately replaced with APPLE again.

The ASPX for the popup dialog is as follows:

```
  <px:PXSmartPanel runat="server" ID="PanelAskForLCCode" LoadOnDemand="True" AutoRepaint="True" Key="LandedCostCodeSelection" CaptionVisible="True" Caption="Select Landed Cost Code" AcceptButtonID="CstButton4" CancelButtonID="CstButton5">
    <px:PXPanel runat="server" ID="CstPanel9">
      <px:PXFormView runat="server" ID="CstFormView10" SkinID="Transparent" Width="100%" SyncPosition="True" DataMember="LandedCostCodeSelection" DataSourceID="ds">
        <Template>
          <px:PXSelector runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector11" DataField="LandedCostCodeID" CommitChanges="True" DataSourceID="ds">
            </px:PXSelector>
        </Template>
      </px:PXFormView>
    </px:PXPanel>
    <px:PXPanel runat="server" ID="LandedCostCodeSelectionButtons" SkinID="Buttons">
      <px:PXButton runat="server" ID="CstButton4" DialogResult="OK" Text="OK" />
      <px:PXButton runat="server" ID="CstButton5" DialogResult="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </px:PXPanel></px:PXSmartPanel>
```

The code for the view that I'm referencing in the dialog is:

```
public PXSelect<LandedCostCode> LandedCostCodeSelection;
```

The code that I'm using to call the dialog is:

```
   if (LandedCostCodeSelection.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
        {
          //rest of code here
        }
```

What am I missing to allow the user to select or type a different Landed Cost Code?

Edit 1:
I have changed the code for the view that I'm referencing in the dialog to:

```
public PXFilter<LandedCostCode> LandedCostCodeSelection;
```

My aspx now looks like this:

```
<px:PXSmartPanel runat="server" ID="PanelAskForLCCode" Key="LandedCostCodeSelection" CaptionVisible="True" Caption="Select Landed Cost Code" AcceptButtonID="CstButton4" CancelButtonID="CstButton5" Width="300px" AutoRepaint="True" LoadOnDemand="True">
    <px:PXFormView runat="server" ID="CstFormView18" CaptionVisible="False" Caption="LC Code Selection" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="LandedCostCodeSelection">
        <Template>
            <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" ID="CstPXLayoutRule19" StartColumn="True" ControlSize="XM" LabelsWidth="S"/>
            <px:PXSelector runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector20" DataField="LandedCostCodeID" CommitChanges="True" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="LandedCostCodeSelection"/>
        </Template>
        <CallbackCommands>
            <Search CommitChanges="True"/>
        </CallbackCommands>
    </px:PXFormView>
    <px:PXPanel runat="server" ID="LandedCostCodeSelectionButtons" SkinID="Buttons">
        <px:PXButton runat="server" ID="CstButton4" DialogResult="OK" Text="OK"/>
        <px:PXButton runat="server" ID="CstButton5" DialogResult="Cancel" Text="Cancel"/>
    </px:PXPanel>
</px:PXSmartPanel>
```

I'm calling the dialog as follows:

```
if (LandedCostCodeSelection.AskExt((graph, view) =>
{
  LandedCostCodeSelection.Cache.Clear();
},true) == WebDialogResult.OK)
{

}
```

I notice that when I click on the selector button and pick a row from the selector (which briefly returns a value to the field which is then overwritten right away) when I click on the selector button again, the selector has remembered the record I last selected.

Finally, if I invoke the dialog as follows:

```
if (LandedCostCodeSelection.AskExt((graph, view) =>
{
  LandedCostCodeSelection.Cache.Clear();
  LandedCostCodeSelection.Current.LandedCostCodeID = "XYZ";
},true) == WebDialogResult.OK)
{

}
```

Then the field is populated with XYZ and if I click OK I can reference the value of XYZ. (But if I use the selector, then the value is cleared and cannot be accessed again.)

Comment: Do you need to set CommitChanges in this case? Can you remove CommitChanges="True"  and try again?

Comment: @JosephCaruana - I tried removing it to the same effect. Additionally, if I type a valid code in the selector without using the grid the valid reverts back to the first landed cost code in the table.

Comment: I'm linking this for whatever it's worth. The dialog call is halfway down the code block, and also at the bottom. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64787680/3718361

Comment: @Deetz - Is the process of using a Dialog this way just to get a filter from the user that I'll later use to select the actual records? Most of the dialogs that I've found in the source code (so far) either are collecting a filter from the user or are asking the user for some information (like a new ID) that are not bound to a data source.

Comment: @Customizer Yeah. It's bound to a ``PXFilter`` but not to a BQL select.

Comment: I am starting to do a lot more dialogs in my code wiht PXFilter and have a similar issue. 
 Are you setting a field in the filter before you AskExt?  I am still working on isolating the exact behavior and workaround, but when I set a field of the filter to a value, I noticed that the results the user enters are ignored on OK.  I have to handle the value I want via PXDefault or SetDefaultExt to allow the user to override it and read the values the user entered.

Comment: @BrianStevens - I haven't been setting a filter beforehand. (Reasonably new to Acumatica).  I noticed that this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822530/update-custom-field-on-popup/49862154) has set a filter as part of the view. But when the user clicks okay, the code uses the filter to select the record(s) required.  Having said that, the SO Copy Order action uses a PXSelector the way that I want.  Would you mind sharing the solution you've found so far?

Comment: @BrianStevens If you want to pre-set a value in a dialog, you have to do it IN the dialog call. I can't find the post where I learned that, but he's doing it correctly.

Comment: @Customizer - Well, I successfully replicated the issue and I'm afraid I got nothin'. You earned my upvote though 

Comment: @Deetz - I appreciate your efforts! I guess my next step is to sacrifice a goat and hope one of the ACM developers sees my question.

Comment: @Deetz - see below.  It looks like the custom DAC and removing the IsKey is the main ideas around the solution.  Not sure if you get a notification by me marking the question as answered so I'm adding this comment.

Comment: @BrianStevens - Notification for you, too, around the solution to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem relies in the definition of the DataView and the DAC used. I have reproduced the issue and this is what I've changed to make it work:

Use a new custom DAC as a source for your view. Note that the field is not bound and is not key (does not have IsKey = true, as in LandedCostCode.LandedCostCodeID:

```
    [Serializable]
    [PXHidden]
    public partial class LandedCostCodeFilter: IBqlTable
    {
      #region LandedCostCodeID
      public abstract class landedCostCodeID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<landedCostCodeID> { }
      [PXString(15, IsUnicode = true)]
      //[PXUnboudDefault("APPLE")] //optional, to preselect a value
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Landed Cost Code",Visibility=PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
      [PXSelector(typeof(Search<LandedCostCode.landedCostCodeID>))]
      public virtual String LandedCostCodeID {get; set}
      #endregion
    }
```

Change the DataView definition, using a PXFilter instead of PXSelect and use the new DAC

```
public PXFilter<LandedCostCodeFilter> LandedCostCodeSelection;
```

Correct that and your dialog should work.

Obs.
If you want to have a value pre-selected when you open the dialog, add [PXUnboudDefault("APPLE")] to the field in the DAC

Not sure how does your button definition look like, but here is what it should be:

```
  public PXAction<POLandedCostDoc> SelectLandedCost;
  [PXButton]
  [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Select Landed Cost Code", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Delete, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Delete)]
  protected void selectLandedCost()
  {
     if(LandedCostCodeSelection.AskExt(true) != WebDialogResult.OK) return;
    
     // do some stuff here
  }
```

Also, my aspx code:

```
<px:PXSmartPanel runat="server" ID="PanelAskForLCCode" Caption="Select Landed Cost Code" CaptionVisible="True" Key="LandedCostCodeSelection">
<px:PXFormView runat="server" ID="CstFormView2" DataMember="LandedCostCodeSelection" SkinID="Transparent" DataSourceID="ds" Height="100%" Width="100%">
  <Template>
    <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" ID="CstPXLayoutRule3" StartColumn="True" />
    <px:PXSelector runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector4" DataField="LandedCostCodeID" CommitChanges="True" AutoRefresh="True" />
    <px:PXPanel runat="server" ID="LandedCostCodeSelectionButtons" SkinID="Buttons">
      <px:PXButton runat="server" ID="CstButton6" DialogResult="OK" Text="OK" />
      <px:PXButton runat="server" ID="CstButton7" DialogResult="Cancel" Text="Cancel" /></px:PXPanel></Template></px:PXFormView></px:PXSmartPanel>
```

Comment: Christmas came early!  Thank you!  One typo: the public virtual String should be string (lower case).

Comment: @Customizer - Is the ``IsKey`` property the only change you made?

Comment: @Customizer, no typo here. I've copied the property from the class LandedCostCode. string is an alias for String :)

Comment: @Lucian - whoops!  My bad!  Thank you again!

Comment: I do something similar.   As you show the defaulting of the initial value, it seems to still behave as I have observed... you default in to get the value in.  In my case, I use a single dialog for a common dialog, but I need to default a reason code based on the type  of action being performed.  I am going to try this again today to make sure it works as I remember, but you can use FieldDefaulting event to add intelligence to the value defaulted.  Then the cache for the filter isn't dirty, and it should allow the user entry to be passed to the subsequent business logic.

Comment: @BrianStevens, the default has nothing to do with the user input. You are right that you can set the default value in PXDefault or PXUnboundDefault attribute, that's easier, or from FieldDefaulting event, if you need more complex logic or other reasons. If the user's input is not set as value of the field upon OK, then check if you are missing the CommitChanges = "True" on the field.